# gem list does not display local gems after using pik

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pik

using pik on windows7 machine, how do i download gems for use by other versions of ruby?

i am using 2 versions of ruby: 1.9.3 and 1.9.2. 1.9.3 is the one that came with the windows installer.

after i ran the commands below, i noticed that local gems were not being displayed correctly:

1) ruby -v

> ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

2) gem list

> ***LOCAL GEMS*** ... lots of gems

3) pik 192
4) ruby -v

> ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

5) gem list

> ***LOCAL GEMS*** ... no gems here

6) pik 193

7) gem list

> ***LOCAL GEMS*** ... no gems here

is pik not able to properly return to ruby version 1.9.3 since it cannot see the gems?

Answer (score 0):

I not see that in windows, but if you are using git bash, it can be fix:

Do this steps:

Open a git bash shell and put:

```
[[ -s $USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc ]] && source $USERPROFILE/.pik/.pikrc

unset GEM_HOME

unset GEM_PATH
```

And it's all.